# Prove that there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ in $F_q[x]$ such that $p(a) = b$ and $p(c) = 0$ for all $c \in F_q\backslash\{a\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $a, b \in F_q$, where $F_q$ is a finite field. Prove that there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ in $F_q[x]$ such that $p(a) = b$ and $p(c) = 0$ for all $c \in F_q\backslash\{a\}$.

It's probably not that hard but I have no idea. Obviously somewhere b needs to be included. I suppose $x-a$ should be in somewhere, though in that form it's opposite of what I want, I need b to show up when $x=a$. I thought of making use of the fact that it is finite, i.e. write $x + (q - a)$, then it would only disappear when $x = a$ but I didn't get much further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you count all the functions $F_{q} \to F_{q}$, and all the *polynomial* functions $F_{q} \to F_{q}$, you will find the same number, so every function is polynomial here.

To get an explicit polynomial realizing a given function, you can use [Lagrange interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean $p(c) = 0$ for all $c \in F_q \setminus \{a\}$, or else the statement is false.

As a hint: Since $F_q$ is finite, the polynomial

$$f(x) = \prod_{\alpha \in F_q \setminus\{a\}} (x - \alpha)$$

makes sense. Evaluate this at $x = a$, and multiply by an appropriate field element.